# How to run NODE.JS (Socket.io) - CENTOS 7 with SSL domain?

Tags: node.js, ssl, websocket, socket.io

My socket.io project "xampp" works fine for localhost.

I have a Centos 7 (cPanel) server. I did everything when I threw files into my server. I wrote the command "nodemon server.js" and the server is running. But I am having SSL-related problems with Client.

My site has SSL. I'm using CloudFlare. For this reason, the *client* cannot communicate with the *server*.

My project is running when I disable SSL.

How does **Socket.io** work with **SSL**?

**CLOUDFLARE**:
[image]

**CHROME CONSOLE LOG:**
[image]

**Client CODE:**

```
var socket = io.connect('https://example.com:1347');
```

**Server.js CODE**

```
var server     = require('https').createServer(),
    io         = require('socket.io')(server),
    port       = 1337;

server.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly if you use CloudFlare. You should know SSL Ports.

**HTTPS ports supported by Cloudflare:**

> 443 2053 2083 2087 2096 8443

Use whichever port is empty on your server. Recommended: (8443)

Connect to your server with PUTTY. Then locate the directory of the domain on your server. If you are using cpanel. Follow this road.

```
cd /home/domainname/public_html
```

You will come to the site's home directory.

Then you need to create the necessary files for SSL to the server. Enter the individual commands below.

```
openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 2048 
openssl req -new -key privatekey.pem -out certrequest.csr 
openssl x509 -req -in certrequest.csr -signkey privatekey.pem -out certificate.pem
```

**Client CODE:**

```
var socket = io.connect('https://example.com:8443', {secure: true});
```

**Server.js CODE**

```
var fs = require('fs');

var https = require('https');
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem')
};
var server = https.createServer(options);
var io  = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var port = 8443; // Enter any of the cloudflare ports.


server.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening : ' + port);
});
```